# How to convert UTM coordinates to Lat/Long using R

Tags: r, geolocation, coordinates, coordinate-systems, gis

I have a large dataset containing UTM coordinates that I want to convert to Long/Lat coordinates. The coordinates are in two columns (i.e. "North" "East"), and additionally "Zone" with the corresponding zone. There are several zones in total.

Any suggestions on a way to convert these columns into Lat/Long and save these into new columns?

Example of the dataset:

```
Longitude Latitude zone  
233243    6571770   33  
262706    6653520   33  
195348    6573696   33   
256880    6645020   33  
260610    6654042   32  
13799     6505840   33
```

Comment: Ummm WGS84 *is* lat-long (well, kinda, but when people say "WGS84" they usually mean EPSG:4326 lat-long). Any chance of a peek at your actual data? Otherwise we're guessing here...

Comment: Indeed, the raw data was "long and lat"
Here is data example with column name in ()
4952 (longitude) 6470636 (latitude)  32 (zone)


The target format looks like e.g:
13.665768 (longitude)   59.739838 (latitude)
I am not to steady on all these formats :P

Comment: These look like UTM coordinates rather than WGS84. Any chance you could paste a few lines of your data into an edit of your question?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I edited the main post :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on the `sp` package, coordinates, and the `spTransform` function. Amongst other things.

For `d` as a data frame:

```
> d
  Longitude Latitude zone
1    233243  6571770   33
2    262706  6653520   33
3    195348  6573696   33
4    256880  6645020   33
5    260610  6654042   32
6     13799  6505840   33
```

The plan is: split into a list by the `zone` id, then for each list element create as a spatial points data frame, use coordinate reference system "+init=epsg:326"+"zone" (eg "+init=epsg:32633" for zone 33), then transform to epsg:4326 lat-long, then rbind the lot together to a single spatial points data frame:

Need these:

```
> library(sp) ; library(raster)
```

Create a list by zone ID:

```
> byzone = split(d,d$zone)
```

Over all the parts, set the coordinates, CRS, and transform:

```
> zdll = lapply(byzone, 
    function(zd){
      coordinates(zd)=~Longitude+Latitude
      proj4string(zd)=paste0("+init=epsg:326",zd$zone[1])
      spTransform(zd, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
     })
```

Now join them up:

```
> dll = do.call(rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame, zdll)
```

If you plot `dll` now you'll see the points on lat-long. If you want the coordinates and to compare with the original coordinates, do this:

```
> cbind(d, coordinates(dll))
  Longitude Latitude zone Longitude Latitude
5    233243  6571770   33  4.712098 59.95395
1    262706  6653520   33 10.327202 59.20086
2    195348  6573696   33 10.750120 59.95049
3    256880  6645020   33  9.663825 59.19259
4    260610  6654042   32 10.656096 59.87099
6     13799  6505840   33  6.663177 58.42136
```

Are they in the expected place?

Comment: Thank you so much!, this indeed solved my problems! :)

Comment: Update: Now it seems like some of the UTM/lat long cordinates corresponds on a map (i.e. http://www.geoplaner.com/) while others have a significant mismatch..
Any suggestions on the possible cause?