# Using sp, terra, raster packages in R to convert Albers Equal Area to Lat/Long

Tags: r, geolocation, coordinates, r-raster, wgs84

I have a .tif file about the ground temperature of a certain region on Earth and I would like to find out the coordinates of the region.

Here is a link to the file I am working on:
[2017001D.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wG-qUjshBFQdeHaYYsUsWQToEVvDy2HM/view?usp=share_link)

Using `raster` package in `R`, I was able to load the .tif file as `RasterLayer` class.

I can extract the coordinate information as

```
> T001D = raster::raster("2017001D.tif")
> T001D
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4255, 5213, 22181315  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : -2926932, 2286068, 1740497, 5995497  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : 2017001D.tif 
names      : X2017001D 

> coords <- raster::xyFromCell(T001D, seq_len(ncell(T001D)))
> head(coords)
            x       y
[1,] -2926432 5994997
[2,] -2925432 5994997
[3,] -2924432 5994997
[4,] -2923432 5994997
[5,] -2922432 5994997
[6,] -2921432 5994997
```

I also used `terra` package to load it as `SpatRaster` class and when I do so I found more info:

```
> T001D = terra::rast("2017001D.tif")
> T001D
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4255, 5213, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : -2926932, 2286068, 1740497, 5995497  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : AEA_WGS_1984 
source      : 2017001D.tif 
name        : 2017001D
```

The coordinate system info seems to be `AEA_WGS_1984`. I looked for it online and found this post:[How to convert WGS84 to Lat/Long using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215686/how-to-convert-wgs84-to-lat-long-using-r) which is similar to my question except I don't have a "zone" number.

It mentioned `sp` package and I feel like I need help with the functions in it now, such as the `CRS` syntax in `spTransform()` function. Can someone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: 1) your link leads to the SO "Home" - Page. 2) What exactly do you want to do? You have a WGS84 Coordinate system. My first instinct would be to try and assign it `CRS 4326` and see where you land (if that is not correct you should move on to some crs optimised for the region your data is supposed to be in - i.e. `CRS 5937` for canada)

Comment: Thank you D.J. I have fixed the link. Sorry about that. The graph is about China region. I looked it up and it seems to be `CRS EPSG:4480`. But what I am confused is really about how to calculate longitude latitude like what the link did but without the "zone" number. I don't know if it is what I should do, and I don't know if it is possible either. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: great, now i think i understand you question. i do not think that you need the zone - you do not seem to have one in the first place. it may be useful when constructing a `proj4-string`. i think you can simply use the standard `sp` functionality. i personally prefer the `sf` package where you can get coordinates by inputting your coordinates into `sf::st_as_sf()` - look at the documentation for the `coords`-argument

Comment: Thank you for the reply, is the `proj4-string` the same as those `"epsg:4326"` codes in the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
library(terra)
T001D <- rast("2017001D.tif")
coords <- crds(T001D, na.rm=FALSE)
geo_coords <- project(coords, crs(T001D), "+proj=longlat")
```

But why would you do that? You probably are approaching what you are after the wrong way. A more common approach (but necessarily what you should do either would be to use project

```
pT001D <- project(T001D, "+proj=longlat")
```

That can change the number of rows a bit and columns because it is a different raster geometry; although you can control that. See `?project`

Comment: Thank you, Robert! I was able to get the right coordinates. I also tried the project() function and I do see that the geometry is changed. In order to control that, I need to set parameters "align" and "method", right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terra` package to have latitude and longitude in degree decimals like

```
library(terra)

T001D = terra::rast("2017001D.tif")

T001D_latlon = project(x = T001D, y = "epsg:4326")

coords <- xyFromCell(T001D_latlon, seq_len(ncell(T001D_latlon)))
head(coords)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your method and it worked. But when I compared the coordinates from the projected `T001D_latlon ` with the coordinate from `T001D `, the number of coordinates is significantly different. Longitude/Latitude one is `[1] 22181315` and WGS84 one is `[1] 28030490 `. Is there anything wrong with the projection?I also applied a link for my `2017001D.tif` file in the question in case you would like to see it.  Thanks again for your reply!